# Run gwt from maven - IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

When trying to run gwt:run from IntelliJ Maven projects panel, this is what I get:

```
[WARNING] GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
[ERROR] Missing required argument 'module[s]'
[ERROR] Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0
[ERROR] DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s] 
[ERROR]
```

What is the work around for this for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this page:

> http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

There you can find all properties you can set for you gwt:run target.

This is how you define the module in you pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>com.yourcompany.YourModule</module>
                </modules>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                <closureCompiler>true</closureCompiler>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xms512m -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</extraJvmArgs>
                <localWorkers>8</localWorkers>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
                <!-- and so on... take a look at the plugin page for more options -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By the way, you should use the latest GWT and GWT Maven Plugin (currently 2.7.0).

Comment: Good link, but the code sample is not the correct indentation of tags in the xml sample, and it is missing the <runTarget>.  Also the <configuration> tag should not be inside the <executions> tag.